# After installing JDK, unable to run .jar

Tags: java, javafx, java-12

During a course it was installed JDK on my computer in order to be able to run eXist database. After this, after executing the command `java -jar fileName.jar` I get the following error.

> Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw Error
>   initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no
>   suitable pipeline found
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
>           ... 1 more Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Windows 10

```
java -version
```

> openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Adopt
>
> OpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Adopt
>
> OpenJDK  (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Try installing java 8

Comment: can you show us your pom.xml please?

Comment: Try installing OpenJFX 12 as well: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Comment: @YCF_L you're assuming there's a POM

Comment: [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) is the way to go as you upgrade the Java version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your log its clear that you'r using JDK-12, and it seems that your jar is developed with JDK-8 where this version of JDK contains the JavaFx library.

But Oracle is removing JavaFX from the JDK-11, so it is no longer present in the JDK-11+, instead you have two solutions :

1. use JDK-8 which contains this JavaFx,
2. or include the JavaFx package or dependency in your project [check the link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx/11)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if with JDK 8 the eXist Database with work, so I rather add the JavaFx. But I'm using java as user, not as developer and after following the link I could not understand what exactly should I do. Maybe you can provide further instructions?

Comment: @OS-50101 from google eXist Database use JDK 8, so rather you have to go with the first solution and run your project with JDK 8 instead of JDK 12, beside you can't modify the project unless there are no upgrade is make it by the team of that project

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to uninstall openjdk12. I googled a lot, they say, you should uninstall it just simple as from settings >> programs. But there was only JRE (Java 8) listed, which I uninstalled. However, running "java.exe --version" still shows I have OpenJDK on my computer. Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: I did you check in variable environment of your OS

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @OS-50101 I think you have another issue, and by convention of SO sites, you have to focus on one problem, I suggest to create a new question, about How to delete java 12, and we will help you Im sure

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled JDK 12 (it was listed in the Apps as AdoptOpen... with no 'java' keyword), then installed both jdk8 and JRE 8. Now I can run both eXist database and the other .jar software (the developer told me that was indeed the issue with *JavaFx*.