# javafx works under ubuntu but not windows

Tags: javafx

under windows i am getting this error:

```
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at
```

the same project (maven) runs fine under ubuntu. i tried to google it but found nothing helpful. the exception tells me nothing. as far as i can tell, all dependencies i need are in my pom file that i cannot share because then stackoverflow won't let me post the question.

i assume this must be a very common problem?
the oracle page talks about an installer, but i can't find one anywhere. there are no instructions, no tutorial, no explanation, nothing useful.

Comment: Provide full stack traces always.  When discussing an outside resource such as "the oracle page", link to it. "An installer" would likely have nothing to do with your question. Up-to-date documentation for JavaFX is at https://openjfx.io.  StackOverflow search of the JavaFX tag for ["QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+QuantumRenderer%3A+no+suitable+pipeline+found) returns 86 duplicates (some may be outdated info).

Comment: i seem to be seriously misunderstanding something. i asssumed javafx was a library you just add to your project, but apparently this is not true, more steps are required and the whole thing is very obscure/complex. i found no useful answers after 30 minutes of searching. many sample projects simply don't work. openjfx.io wasn't helpful either, their maven sample leads exactly to the error i posted.

Comment: "i asssumed javafx was a library you just add to your project" -> it is, but with a couple of caveats: 1. It uses the Java 9 module system, which a lot of other libraries don't, so it brings with it the complexity and overhead of the module system. 2. It contains native components in its modules so the modules deployed need to be the right classified versions for a given setup. 3.  It is trickier to package and distribute because of the first two points. 4. You need to use a compatible JDK (11+).

Comment: "openjfx.io wasn't helpful either, their maven sample leads exactly to the error i posted." -> if you followed the openjfx.io instructions exactly and the resultant hello world app did not run your target machine, then perhaps the target machine (e.g. graphics card) is not supported by JavaFX.

Comment: Use the command prompt to check which version of `Java` is on your machine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856943/after-installing-jdk-unable-to-run-jar

Comment: trashgod wrote a [version check app](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/c3e0fa8480b11f93b9ab08e597a45a5a), but if your system is deficient, it may not run.

Comment: I'd be interested to learn your results with @jewelsea's suggestion; I recently noticed that this [`archetype`](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven) creates a similar application.

Comment: This seems to be the same as this question: [JavaFX Maven Project cant be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652633/javafx-maven-project-cant-be-started), though the other question is much better written, which allowed mipa to quickly provide a correct answer for it.